# Is there a python script to generate Blizzard API Access Token?

Tags: python, world-of-warcraft

I'm fairly new to coding but I'm trying to work on a bot that pulls some data from the blizzard api. The bot I have works fine but I'm having to go in and manually change the url for the json data every time the access token changes. I understand the token changes every 24 hours but i can't imagine developers have to constantly go to the console and pull up the new url with updated access token every day. I've been looking around through the blizzard OAuth documentation and I found the following code someone had posted for python:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def create_access_token(client_id, client_secret, region = 'us'):
    url = "https://%s.battle.net/oauth/token" % region
    body = {"grant_type": 'client_credentials'}
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
    response = requests.post(url, data=body, auth=auth)
    return response.json()
create_access_token()
```

but when i pass my client id and my client secret to this, I don't get any information. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Had you seen [this page](https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth/authorization-code-flow) in the documentation? I haven't used the API before, so I might be misunderstanding things.

Comment: Noah, in case you've resolved this, could you write up the approach you've settled on as an answer to your own question? I'm sure it would help a lot of new developers using the Battle.net API

Comment: Also I think the [client credential flow](https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth/client-credentials-flow) is more relevant and is what your code snippet is based on. Try changing `data=body` to `json=body` or to use json.dumps to turn your python dictionary into a JSON string.

Also, inspect the the `response.content` and `response.status_code`, they might indicate an error message.

Comment: Sorry for the stream of consciousness comments, but I went ahead and created an API client for myself and tested out your snipper: It returned `500: Internal Server Error`, not very helpful! But, using the curl example I was able to get a very similar piece of working Python code, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an online CURL to Python Requests ansible tool like [this](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to get the correct requests format from the documentation CURL example of the [client credential flow](https://develop.battle.net/documentation/guides/using-oauth/client-credentials-flow):

### curl

```sh
curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} -d grant_type=client_credentials https://us.battle.net/oauth/token
```

### python

```py
import requests

def create_access_token(client_id, client_secret, region = 'us'):
    data = { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' }
    response = requests.post('https://%s.battle.net/oauth/token' % region, data=data, auth=(client_id, client_secret))
    return response.json()

response = create_access_token(YOUR_CLIENT_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET)
print(response)
```